# How to boost certain term (clause) in query in Lucene.NET 4.8

Tags: c#, lucene, lucene.net

Suppose we have a MoreLikeThis query (or any other **existing query**)

```
MoreLikeThis mlt = new MoreLikeThis(reader);
Query query = mlt.Like(some_document);
```

which looks something like this:

```
field:term1^2.0 field:term2^1.5 field:term3^0.5
```

What am I trying to do is to **change the boost factor value for certain term in this query**.

For instance, I might want to multiply boost factor of `term2` by `2` to get:

```
field:term1^2.0 field:term2^3.0 field:term3^0.5
```

Obviously, it could be done in a "crude way" by converting query to string -
 `query.ToString()`, manually parsing this string and searching for `term2`, multiplying value behind the caret by `2`, replacing the original value by new value and lastly converting the string back to Lucene `Query` object.

However, my question is **if Lucene already does have some more elegant and convenient built-in tools for editing existing queries**.